# How to check if a template argument is an specific type in C++

Tags: c++, hashtable

I'm having some trouble to detect if a template argument is a string in C++. I have to find out if the data is a string because I have to insert it in a hash table. It can be a string or an integer

```cpp
size_t aux = capacidade();  //capacity of the hash table

int qtd_indice = capacidade(); //capacity of the hash table
if (!std::is_integral<T>::dado){
  int somatorio = 0; //sum of the convertion to int
  int expo = -1;  //the exponential of the method
  for(unsigned int i = 0; i < dado.length();i++)
  {
    somatorio += pow(dado[i]*31,qtd_indice - expo); //incrementing each conversion of int 
    expo--; 
  }
  size_t indice_esperado = somatorio % aux; //finding the expected indice of the data in the hash table
  return indice_esperado; //returning the expected indice
}
size_t indice_esperado = dado % aux;  // here i'm doing the same thing but the data is a integer so 
return indice_esperado;
```

[image: Code image]

Comment: `if (!std::is_integral<T>::dado)` ->`if constexpr (!std::is_integral<T>::value)` and add `else` for the other part.

Comment: or `std::is_same_v<T,std::string>`

Comment: but overloads `int to_int(int, int qtd_indice);int to_int(std::string&, int qtd_indice)` seems a good alternative.